# Randomic distribution

Tags: elementary-set-theory, probability-distributions, random

Suppose I have X elements [A,B,C,D,...] and Y subsets of X of max length 4.

Suppose the subsets are build up randomly, is there a way to compute the average number of subsets an item of X is an element of ?

EDIT:

I have a file like this:
where X are the numbers between 0 and 99
with 100 000 rows, which represent the subsets
and I get that singletons are present in approximately 2500 rows
i.e. `E(W) = 100000 * 0.025`
while according to the formula it should be   : `E(W) = 1000000 * 0,040`

```
82 73 62 
21 49 11 
28 
54 5 10 
42 
31 35 
89 5 
42 88 9 
62 
15 77 72 83 
33 83 
0 
73 88 
84 10 
61 98 78 
22 13 6 
10 66 
76 34 8 0 
92 39 
52 97 14 
95 7 46 6 
79 30 
74 29 73 49 
23 83 
63 
99 18 68 10 
59 64 8 52 
21 85
```

code snippet:

```
        int j = 0; // row counter
        while(j < 100000)
        {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            int max = r.nextInt(4) + 1; // gives me an int between 1 and 4
            for(int jj = 0;jj <max;jj++) // cycle to generate subset
            {
                int rand;

                // produce random number between 0 and 99
                do
                {   
                 rand = r.nextInt(100);
                }
                while(!notPresent(""+rand,list)); // retry if it's been already inserted in the list  

                list.add(""+rand);
                writer.print(rand+" "); // write set element
            }

     writer.println();  // new line character
     j++;   
    }
```

Comment: The $Y$ subsets, need they be different? Are all subsets, whatever their size, equally likely?

Comment: No, subsets need not to be different,yes all subsets are equally likely the only constraint is max size equals to 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We change notation a little. Let $A$ be an $N$-element set. We choose at random a multiset  $C$ of  $m$ subsets of $A$, each of cardinality $\le 4$, with all choices equally likely.

Let $a$ be a specific element of  $A$, and let random variable $W$ be the number of sets in $C$ that contain $a$. Let $U_i=1$ if on the $i$-th choice of a set, our chosen set contained $a$, and let $U_i=0$ otherwise. Then $W=U_1+\cdots+U_m$.  By the linearity of expectation we have
$$E(W)=E(U_1)+E(U_2)+\cdots +E(U_m)=mE(U_1).$$

So now all we need is to find $E(U_1)$, that is, the probability that $U_1=1$.

There are $\binom{N}{4}$ possible sets of $4$, $\binom{N}{3}$ sets of $3$, and so on, down to the empty set if you wish, but I will (arbitrarily) not allow that as a choice.

The probability  than a $4$-set contains $a$ is $4/N$, and the probability that a $3$-set contains $a$ is $3/N$, and so on. 
Thus
$$E(U_1)=\frac{(4/N)\binom{N}{4}+(3/N)\binom{N}{3}+(2/N)\binom{N}{2}+(1/N)\binom{N}{1}}{\binom{N}{4}+\binom{N}{3}+\binom{N}{2}+\binom{N}{1}}.$$
The numerator simplifies to $\binom{N}{3}+\binom{N}{2}+\binom{N}{1}+1$.
Putting things together we find that
$$E(W)=m\cdot \frac{ \binom{N}{3}+\binom{N}{2}+\binom{N}{1}+1}{\binom{N}{4}+\binom{N}{3}+\binom{N}{2}+\binom{N}{1}}.$$

**Remark:** You might wish to change the model in various ways. The basic technique detailed above probably can, with small changes, still be used.

In particular, it may be that for your application you are interested not in **subsets**, but rather in **sequences** of length $\le 4$. The basic analysis will be much the same, with small differences of detail, powers instead of binomial coefficients.

**Added:** If the size of the set is randomly chosen to be between $1$ and $4$, then $E(U_1)$ changes. We use a conditional expectation argument.

If the size is $1$, then the expectation is $\frac{1}{N}$, if the size is $2$ the expectation is $\frac{2}{N}$ and so on, so
$$E(U_1)=\frac{10}{4N}.$$

Comment: Thank you a lot sir,I will study your post and try to unerstand it.

Comment: You are welcome. I do not know what is most suited for your work, so I interpreted the word "set" in the standard way. If you need to use a different model, I expect you can use a suitable modification. The basic trick that makes things work is the use of indicator random variables, the $U_i$ of the answer, If you run into difficulties, you can ask a new question, preferably specifying the modified problem in full detail.

Comment: I needed that formula to see if it meets experimental data, now I'm seeing that it does not I get an half of that probability, is there any chance there's something incorrect in the formula ?

Comment: Have you considered in the formula that also the size of the subsets are choses randomly between 1 and 4 ?

Comment: I have proofread it, things look fine, with the interpretation that you are at each stage producing a *set* of distinct elements. And that any set is just as likely to be produced as any other, so the probability of a specific $4$-set or specific $2$-set is the same. If you specify more closely the actual process by which you choose "sets," I can if necessary modify the model to fit that.  For example, if you decide on $4$, $3$, $2$, or $1$ with equal probabilities, that will shrink things considerably.  I assumed that any two sets are equally likely, so the $4$-sets dominate.

Comment: please see my edit, thanks for your time and help.

Comment: yes,subsets sizes are random chosen  1<=size <= 4, can it be the casue of the imprecision in your model ?

Comment: The edit does not help much. But the list you give indicates to me that $4$-sets seem to be underrepresented if all possible sets are equally likely. A clearer description of how sets are generated would make it possible to see whether the model I used should be modified. The key, to repeat, is the **process** by which we generate a set. In your list, if I read it right, there are roughly as many $3$-sets as $4$-sets, and there also seem to be "too many" $2$-sets and $1$-sets. So again, how do we produce a specific set?

Comment: I can paste the snippet of java code I'm using, it might help ?

Comment: So you decide on the numbers $1$ to $4$, each with equal probability $1/4$, and **then** produce a set?  Then there should be a lot of singletons, more than your file indicates. The formula can be modified to use this model, but I need to be reasonably sure about what is happening. So the process needs first to be described with complete clarity. The rest, for me, is easy.

Comment: Yes I commented the code I hope it can help you and again I don't know how to thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: I have performed another test, your model and formula work fine when each itemset is size exactly 4

Comment: Foe size exactly $4$ the last $3$ items in the numerator and denominator disappear. But this makes no real difference, the dominant term is the first.

Comment: Given your last edit how is the formula of E(W) to be modified ?

Comment: The added material uses the assumption that sizes $1$ to $4$ are equally likely. That gives expectation $m \cdot \frac{10}{4N}$.

Comment: can you explain me how did you get those numbers ? I don't get it

Comment: It is a conditional expectation calculation. Let $S$ be the set size. Then $S=1,2,3,4$ each with probability $\frac{1}{4}$. The expected value of $U_i$ given $S=i$ is $\frac{i}{N}$. So the expectation of $U_1$ is $(1/4)(1/N)+(1/4)(2/N)+(1/4)(3/N)+(1/4)(4/N)$, which is $10/(4N)$. For the full expectation multiply by $m$.

Comment: Ok now I get it, thank you very much Sir for your time and effort ;)